# VBA BuiltInDocumentProperties

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that sits in WorkbookA and retrieves data from WorkbookB. I want to return the "Last Save Time" for WorkbookB and put it into a cell within WorkbookA. In the code below "lastsave" is a named range referring to a cell in WorkbookA.

I have tried the following from various websites and similar questions but to no avail. I suspect the solution has to do with objects, items in a list, values, etc. but I cannot seem to put my finger on it.

1) Error: Object Doesn't support this property or method

```
 Dim lastsavetime as Object
 set lastsavetime = Workbooks(B).BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
 Workbooks(A).Sheet1.Range("lastsave").Value = lastsavetime
```

2) Error: Automation Error, Unspecified Error

```
 Dim lastsavetime as variant
 set lastsavetime = Workbooks(B).BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
 Workbooks(A).Sheet1.Range("lastsave").Value = lastsavetime
```

3) Error: Method 'Value' of object 'DocumentProperty' failed

```
 Workbooks(A).Sheet1.Range("lastsave").Value = Workbooks(B).BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time").Value
```

4) Error: Object Doesn't support this property or method

```
 Workbooks(A).Sheet1.Range("lastsave").Value = Workbooks(B).BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time").Value
```

5) Error: Method 'Value' of object 'DocumentProperty' failed

```
 Dim propertylist as DocumentProperties
 Set propertylist = Workbooks(B).BuiltinDocumentProperties

 Workbooks(A).Sheet1.Range("lastsave").Value = (propertylist.Item("Last Save Time"))
```

Comment: `.Sheet` is not a property of the `Workbook` object?  Also, you may need to do `.Value = lastsavetime.value`

Comment: Good point on .Sheet for Workbook object. I added Workbooks(A) to make it clear where the data was going for purposes of the question but in reality I just have Sheet1.Range.... My apologies I can see how that was misleading. I will try the .Value = lastsavetime.value as you suggest.

Comment: It may also raise an error if the property hasn't been set, i.e., on a new/un-saved Workbook.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Workbooks(A).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(lastsave).Formula = Workbooks(B).BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
```

Here:
`A` is a string holding the name of your destination wb ("SaveTimeLog.xlsx")
`B` is a string holding the name of the wb for which you're capturing last save time e.g. "MyWB.xlsx"
`Sheet1` is the name of the worksheet where you want to write last save time e.g. "Sheet1"
`lastsave` is a string holding a reference to the cell where the info goes, e.g., "G4"

As is this will write last save time as a numeric value. To get it in a human-friendly format you can either format the destination cell as a date/time, or covert the right-hand side of the statement above by enclosing it in CStr().

**FYI** Workbooks(A).Sheet1 fails because Workbooks(A) is a workbook object. There is no Sheet1 method or property of a workbook object.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your workbook B is opened, this works for a module in workbook A.

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("lastsave").RefersToRange.Value = Workbooks(B).BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

- In errors 1, 3, 4 and 5: the object Workbook does not support the method Sheet1. Use `Workbooks(A).Sheets(1)`
- In error 2 it should have been the same message. I cant tell why the error message had changed. Something went worng.

All in all, it is the `.Sheet1` that is causing all this trouble. use `.sheets(1)` instead.